# Appended cloned form refreshes page but shouldn't

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a normal form that at first is one form, but when the user clicks on the "#addOne" button, a clone of the previous form is displayed using jQuery. Form data is relayed using Ajax, and when the user clicks to submit the form, the form does not refresh because of e.preventDefault(); The problem is that the dynamically created forms are refreshing the page for some reason. The first form that is not dynamically created does not refresh the page. What is the cause for this? How do I make my dynamically created forms not refresh the page?

***Each form is numbered, and each form is one less than its previous. The numbers will be used in my SQL WHERE clause. I want the cloned forms to be separate forms, For example, if I enter values for form 9 and click submit, and then enter values for form 8 the information won't collide with each other. Form 8's button should not submit for all the other forms***

Here's my code and the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2c2xL0cz/

**HTML**

```
<div class="article_properties">
                        <form class="article_properties_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <p style="display: inline">Page Number</p><div style="background-color: #FF355E; padding: 5px; display: inline; margin-left: 5px"<p class="pageNumber"></p></div>
                        <textarea style="display: none" class="inputNumber" name="pageNumber"></textarea>
                        <p>Image</p>
                        <input type="file">
                            <p>Subtitle</p>
                            <input type="text" name="subtitle">

                            <p>Text</p>
                            <textarea name="text" rows="4"></textarea>
                            <input id="properties_btn" type="submit" value="Submit/Update">
                            <hr style="border: 1px dotted lightgray; margin-bottom: 50px">
                        </form>

                        <div id="addOne" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: orange; border-radius: 50%"><p style="text-align: center; line-height: 25px">+</p></div>

                    </div> <!--End of article properties div-->
```

**jQuery/Ajax**

```
var numPages = 10;
$('.pageNumber').text(numPages);
$('.inputNumber').text(numPages);
$('#addOne').click(function()
            {

                numPages--;
                        var articlePropsTemplate = $('.article_properties_form:last').clone();
                        $('.article_properties_form').append(articlePropsTemplate);
                        $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPages);
                        $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPages);

            });

            $('.article_properties_form').on('submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {

                        }
                    });
                })
```

Comment: Why not use a `<button type="button"></button>` instead of an `<input>`? Also, you are missing an ending `>` on your page number div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are copying the `form` element, then appending that `form` to the previous `form`. `$('.article_properties_form').append(articlePropsTemplate);` is the actual problem, you want `$('.article_properties').append(articlePropsTemplate);`.

```js
var numPages = 10;
$('.pageNumber').text(numPages);
$('.inputNumber').text(numPages);
$('#addOne').click(function() {

  numPages--;
  var articlePropsTemplate = $('.article_properties_form:last').clone();
  $('.article_properties').append(articlePropsTemplate);
  $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPages);
  $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPages);

});

$('.article_properties_form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {

    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article_properties">
  <form class="article_properties_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p style="display: inline">Page Number</p>
    <div style="background-color: #FF355E; padding: 5px; display: inline; margin-left: 5px">

      <p class="pageNumber"></p>
    </div>
    <textarea style="display: none" class="inputNumber" name="pageNumber"></textarea>
    <p>Image</p>
    <input type="file">
    <p>Subtitle</p>
    <input type="text" name="subtitle">

    <p>Text</p>
    <textarea name="text" rows="4"></textarea>
    <input id="properties_btn" type="submit" value="Submit/Update">
    <hr style="border: 1px dotted lightgray; margin-bottom: 50px">
  </form>

  <div id="addOne" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: orange; border-radius: 50%">
    <p style="text-align: center; line-height: 25px">+</p>
  </div>

</div>
<!--End of article properties div-->
```

On a side note, it might be better to use a `button` element with `type="button"`. Then you can use an `onclick` event instead of `onsubmit`. That's just a suggestion, either way will work.

Comment: Will a type=button still relay the information to my PHP isset if statement?

Comment: @user2896120 Yes, as long as you are using `isset()`, because the value for it will be blank.

Comment: Also, I am not at home right now, but are the cloned forms considered separate forms? For example, if I enter values for form 9 and click submit, and then enter values for form 8 the information won't collide with each other? Form 8's button won't submit for all the other forms?

Comment: I made an update to the answer, to reflect the new information you gave me. As far as the forms go, you'll need to send something to identify what page you are submitting, e.g. an `input` with the value of the page number.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! I'll check it out when I get back home :)

Comment: Hmm, even with this code the page seems to refresh for me with the dynamic forms...

Comment: Ok, I added a `return false;` at the end of the submit routine. This should definitely prevent a refresh.